# Elasticsearch pagination split up

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, kibana, elk

Im new to Elasticsearch and had to face a scenario stuck up on what is the right way to do it or if its possible, so the scenario is like this,

suppose there is a todo app and a page where all todo created by users are listed by pagination of 5 per page.

if user A created 4 todos,
user B created 4 todos,
user C created 1 todo.

so my page result has to be like

page 1:

user C's 1 todo
user B's 2 todo
user A's 2 todo

page 2:

user B's 2 todo
user A's 2 todo

ie, if a user created more than 2 todos at the same time only shows the last created 2 todos on one page, the remaining 2 on the next page, and goes on.

Comment: Please put more details like what is your expected output. it seems like you have posted half question.